# How to bind GridView Images to a Database in metro style app?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I create a GridView App and want to bind the images in the GridView to values from a DataBase, the values in the DataBase are stored as image data type.

Comment: Please improve your question, what did you already tried? Provide some more details about your language you are using, the db etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You have to expose the images through a web service first. WinRT apps don't talk to database directly - there is no API for that yet AFAIK. Maybe someone created some proxy like the [one for SQLite](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/tree/master/src/Callisto/Data), but you would then still need to download the image first.

Comment: yes you are write , i didn't intend that ,i already get the images from web service  as strings (binary) and i want to make something to bind the image tag in the GridView with those values

Comment: OK then you already have another question where you ask about the same thing then. Try asking more specific questions - like "how to save an image retrieved from a web service to be able to display it in a XAML GridView".